Next.js - re-requesting data from the server when returning to the page
I'm sorry for the grammar, I'm writing through a translator.
The problem is as follows: I use (version 14.1.4) there is a page with product group cards. by clicking on the group card, we go to the group page (/group/[slug]) and at this moment I receive data about the products in the group from the server. it's all right. but if you immediately return to the previous page (/) and click on the card of the same group again, the group will open, but the data will be taken from the cache. if you do this several times, then after 30 seconds, each time you visit the group page, the data will start downloading again from the server (I need this every time I log in to the group)
in the fetch component, dynamic = 'force-dynamic' is used.
I found out that this is not a Next problem, but a React, it caches paths on the client.
how can this be prohibited?
It is advised to stick cookies to the request, this prohibits the request cache. yes, it works - but when you return to the previous page, it will scroll up, since information about the previous page is not saved
